# Перерисовка datagridview при разворачивании окна

Tags: c#, winforms

Перерисовка ячеек таблицы происходит в CellPainting по примеру [отсюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?view=net-5.0). После сворачивания и разворачивания окна происходит следующее:
До
[image]
После
[image]

Перерисовка в CellPainting происходит так:

```
using (Brush border_brush = new SolidBrush(<COLOR>))
{
    using (Pen border_pen = new Pen(border_brush, <WIDTH>))
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(
           e.CellBounds.X + 2,
           e.CellBounds.Y + 2,
           e.CellBounds.Width - 6,
           e.CellBounds.Height - 6
       );

       e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(border_pen, rect);
    }
}

e.Handled = true;
```

Полагаю, валится благополучно после обновления окна. Но какое событие происходит в датагииде при этом? И надо ли просто продублировать там отрисовку? Заранее спасибо

Comment: `надо ли просто` - Надо просто использовать отладчик и поставить точку останова в интересущий вас метод. Тогда будет понятно, что и когда вызывается, и вызывается ли оно вообще.

Comment: @aepot, перерисовка есть только в CellPainting. В этом событии все отрабатывает без ошибок. По всей видимости, проблема в другом событии (которое обрабатывается системой). Поэтому и хотелось бы выяснить, что идет после CellPainting

Comment: Чем больше я вижу таких вопросов - тем больше люблю WPF. Еще раз: вы можете подобрать несколько событий, создать обработчики, поставить точки останова, смотреть что за чем и когда вызывается прямо в отладчике. Про жизненный цикл рендера DGV вам сейчас вряд-ли кто подскажет, ну если не сделает за вас то что я выше написал. Я предполагаю, что проблема может быть в двойной буферизации, попробуйте ради эксперимента отключить. Если поможет - значит проблема не в отрисовке, а в восстановлении буфера. Как победить - не знаю, задача творческая. Может я ошибаюсь, лет 100 не писал под формы ничего.

Comment: Вот эта стрелка в круге откуда берётся? | `e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true); e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);` - если отрисовываете рамочку, то и фон, и содержимое ячейки тоже нужно отрисовать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, как раз содержимое в этот раз и не отрисовал руками) Спасибо! Не подскажите, где можно о подобных вещах почитать, кроме как на MSDN?)